# How to reliably re-calculate blob sha1 hash (or another identity) from (user) text content and escape line-end/whitespace hell?

Tags: git, node.js, hash, newline, sha

I have some code for Node.js that pull text files from Git (local Git or via the Github API) and uses the commit/tree/blob data in various scenarios. But I have problems with the line endings and recalculating sha hashes after I (or the user) uses the files.

The data consist of source-code. It gets downloaded/used/linked/imported to a users project directory and used in development. I was hoping to use the git blob hashes to check for changes relative to the source blob.

My setup:

I'm on Windows but use Travis-CI and a VM to run builds.

I use this function to calculate the sha1-hash as hex-string:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
function blobShaHex(data:NodeBuffer, encoding?:string):string {
    return crypto.createHash('sha1').update('blob ' + data.length + '\0').update(data, encoding).digest('hex');
}
```

So far this seems to work very well: data read as raw Buffers straight from the repos match their hashe, same with utf8 content.

Problem:

In practical user-use of the blob content the line endings break the blob sha1:

The file might get checked-in into a VCS and then get mangled by line-end conversions. Also the user's IDE may normalise line-breaks to user preference, even if the user never saves the file. Many other things may happen.

Note: my code is *not* pulling the blob *from* the Git repo where the files end up. Instead it is a separate thing (like dependency manager) that just moves blob-originating files around, which may-or-may not get checked in somewhere.

To make things extra messy I have no full control over the source-repo's line-endings so there is no guarantee about which style then come down with. Might even be mixed conventions (if that technically possible?).

Questions:

Is there some way to revert to the original linebreaks or otherwise verify a match? I could pull the original file again and do stuff with it.

Any advice on handling this would be welcome.

--

Now I typed this all up I'm starting to think it might be a really non-practical idea to attempt this. Maybe it'd be better to force normalise and create&track my own checksums or use some clever white-space ignoring diff thing?

Comment: I think you're always going to fight this problem, because the hashes only make sense inside of the system git provides. You're outside the walls, and as you said, there's a potential translation layer between you and git, and in fact, several of them (git settings, IDE settings, etc). I'm not sure of your use case, but I think it's highly unstable anyway, given that you're talking about the user checking the code into a (different?) VCS, and using it in an IDE. Out there the content is totally 'in the wild,' and has no connection to any blob sha-1.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was coming to realise. I'll go with a custom hasher that normalises instead of using git's blobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go with a custom hasher that normalises linebreaks and such instead of using Git's blobs sha hashes.

Like @gary-fixler commented on my question:

> "Out there the content is totally 'in the wild,' and has no connection to any blob sha-1."